# I am making a cutomer profile (a sample) and I am getting the error - POST http://localhost:3000/cusprofiles/add 400 (Bad Request) when I add data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want to make a customer profile for a vet clinic and according to my code, I am unable to insert and edit customer details. I cannot find where I have gone wrong. Only get method is working. Can someone help me please?

****This is my js file in models****

```
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const cusprofileSchema = new Schema({
        Pet_Name: {type: String, requied : true},
        Owner_Name: {type: String, required:true},
        PetAge: {type: String, required:true},
        cusprofileImage: {type: String, required: true},
        vaccination: {type: String, required:true},
        medication: {type: String, required:true},
        other: {type: String, required:true},
        next_meetup: {type: Date, required:true},  
    });
    
    const CusProfiles = mongoose.model("CusProfiles", cusprofileSchema);
    
    
    module.exports = CusProfiles;
```

**This is my js file in routes**

```
        const res = require("express/lib/response");
        const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
        const router = express.Router();
        const multer = require("multer");
        const CusProfiles = require('../models/cusprofiles');
        const Medication = require('../models/cusprofiles')
        
        
        
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
           destination: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, "./vet/public/uploads/");
            },
            filename: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, file.originalname);
            }
        });
        
        const upload = multer({storage: storage});
        
        
        //Request get all profiles
        router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
            CusProfiles.find()
            .then(cusprofile => res.json(cusprofile))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: $(err'))
        });
        
        
        //Request get all profiles
        router.get('/view', (req, res)=> {
            Medication.find()
            .then(cusprofile => res.json(cusprofile))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: $(err'))
        });
        
        
        //Request add new profile
        
        router.post('/add', upload.single("cusprofileImage"), (req, res) => {
            const newCusProfile = new CusProfiles({
                Pet_Name: req.body.Pet_Name,
                Owner_Name: req.body.Owner_Name,
                PetAge: req.body.PetAge,
                cusprofileImage: req.file.originalname,
                vaccination: req.body.vaccination,
                medication: req.body.medication,
                other: req.body.other,
                next_meetup: Date(req.body.next_meetup),
                       
            });
        
            newCusProfile.save()
            .then(() => res.json("The new Profile posted successfully!"))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ${err}'));
        });
        
        
        //Request find profile by Id
        router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
            CusProfiles.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(cusprofile => res.json(cusprofile))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ${err}'));
        });
        
        
        //Request find profile by Id and update
        
        router.put("/update/:id", upload.single("cusprofileImage"), (req, res) => {
            CusProfiles.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(cusprofile => {
                cusprofile.Pet_Name = req.body.Pet_Name;
                cusprofile.Owner_Name = req.body.Owner_Name;
                cusprofile.PetAge = req.body.PetAge;
                cusprofile.cusprofileImage =  req.file.originalname;
                cusprofile.vaccination = req.body.vaccination;
                cusprofile.medication = req.body.medication;
                cusprofile.other = req.body.other;
                cusprofile.next_meetup = Date(req.body.next_meetup);
                
        
                cusprofile
                .save()
                .then(() => res.json("The Profile is Updated successfully"))
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ${err}'));
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ${err}'));
        });
        
        
        //Request find profile by Id and delete
        router.delete("/:id", (req, res) =>{
            CusProfiles.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
            .then(() => res.json("The profile is DELETED!"))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ${err}'));
```

```
    });
    
    
    module.exports = router;


**what includes in server**
```

```
        const mongoose = require("mongoose");
        const cors = require("cors");
        
        
        require('dotenv').config();
        
        const app = express();
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
        
        app.use(cors());
        app.use(express.json());
        
        
        const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
        
        mongoose.connect(uri, {
            useNewUrlParser:true,
            useUnifiedTopology:true
        });
        
        const connection = mongoose.connection;
        connection.once("open", ()=>
            console.log("MongoDB connection established successfully!")
        );
        
        const cusprofilesRouter = require("./routes/cusprofiles.js");
        app.use("/cusprofiles", cusprofilesRouter);
        
        
        app.listen(port, () => console.log('The app is running on Port: ${port}'));
```

**This is my App.js**

```
    import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from "axios";
    import "./App.css";
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    import Header from "./components/layouts/Header";
    import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
    import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";
    import CusProfiles from "./components/CusProfiles";
    import CusProfile from "./components/CusProfile";
    import AddNewMedication from "./components/AddNewMedication";
    import EditMedication from "./components/EditMedication";
    import AddCusProfile from "./components/AddCusProfile";
    import EditCusProfile from "./components/EditCusProfile";
    import Medication from "./components/Medication";
    
    
    
    
    function App() {
       
      const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
      useEffect(()=> {
        axios
        .get("/cusprofiles")
        .then(res => setPosts(res.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
      });
    
    
     
      return (
        <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Navbar/>
        
        <Route 
        exact path="/view" 
        render={() => <Medication posts={posts}/>}
        />
    
        
    
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <CusProfiles posts={posts}/>}
        />
    
     
       <Route 
        path="/cusprofile/:id" 
        render={(props) => <CusProfile {...props} posts={posts}/>}
        />
    
    
        <Route 
        path="/add"
        render={(props) => <AddNewMedication {...props} posts={posts}/>}
        />
     
      
        <Route 
        path="/update/:id" 
        render={(props) => <EditMedication {...props} posts={posts}/>}
        />
    
        <Route 
        path="/update/:id" 
        render={(props) => <EditCusProfile {...props} posts={posts}/>}
        />
    
    
      <Route exact path="/add-profile" component={AddCusProfile}/>
    
      {/*<Route exact path="/edit-profile" component={EditCusProfile}/>*/}
    
     
        
        <Footer/>
        
      </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**This is AddCusProfile.js**

```
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const AddCusProfile = () => {
      const [Pet_Name, setPetName] = useState("");
      const [Owner_Name, setOwnerName] = useState("");
      const [PetAge, setAge] =useState("");
      const [vaccination, setVacc] =useState("");
      const [medication, setMedi] =useState("");
      const [other, setOther] =useState("");
      const [next_meetup, setMeet] =useState("");
      const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
      const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
      
    
     const onChangeFile = e => {
       setFileName (e.target.files[0]);
      }
    
      const changeOnClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append("Pet_Name", Pet_Name);
        formData.append("Owner_Name", Owner_Name);
        formData.append("PetAge", PetAge);
        formData.append("vaccination", vaccination);
        formData.append("medication", medication);
        formData.append("other", other);
        formData.append("next_meetup", next_meetup);
        formData.append("cusprofileImage", fileName);
      
        
    
        setPetName("");
        setOwnerName("");
        setAge("");
        setVacc("");
        setMedi("");
        setOther("");
        setMeet("");
       
    
    
        axios.post("/cusprofiles/add", formData)
        .then(res => setMessage(res.data))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      };
    
    
    
      return (
        <AddProfileContainer>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Add New Pet Profile</h1><br></br>
        <span className="message">{message}</span><br></br>
    
        <form onSubmit={changeOnClick} encType="multipart/form-data">
    
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Pet_Name">Pet Name</label>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={Pet_Name}
        onChange={e => setPetName(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"  
        placeholder="Enter Pet Name"></input><br></br>
      </div>
    
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Owner_Name">Owner Name</label>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={Owner_Name}
        onChange={e => setOwnerName(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"  
        placeholder="Enter Owner Name"></input><br></br>
      </div>
    
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="PetAge">Pet Age</label>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={PetAge}
        onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"  
        placeholder="Enter Pet Age"></input><br></br>
      </div>
    
      
    
      <div className = "form-group">
        <label htmlFor="file">Choose Profile Image</label><br></br>
        <input
          type="file"
          filename = "cusprofileImage"
          className="form-control-file"
          onChange={onChangeFile}
          /><br></br><br></br>
      </div>
    
      
    
    
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Submit Details
        </button>
        
    </form>
    </div>
    </AddProfileContainer>
      )
     };
    
    export default AddCusProfile;
    
    //Main Container
    const AddProfileContainer = styled.div`
      margin: 3rem auto;
      padding: 4rem;
      width: 51.25rem;
    
      h1 {
        font-weight:900;
        color: var(--dark-green);
      }
    
      .btn-primary {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        background: var(--dark-green);
        border:none;
        &:hover {
          background: var(--light-green);
        }
      }
    
    
      .message {
        font-weight: 900;
        color: tomato;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    }
    
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use `findByIdAndUpdate(),` instead of `findById` in router.put method.